# How to speed up servlet that calls 2 web-services?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services, servlets

I have a servlet that calls 2 web-services. Those 2 web services are called in separate threads. In my servlet thered (class that extends HttpServlet), i start those 2 threads and then wait in a while loop, until those threads finish. 
This consumes quite a lot CPU (almost 100%) on a JBOSS and Tomcat server util that while loop finishes.
I created code for WS clients with wsiimport tool. It takes quite some time to create WSClient objects for every HTTP request (calling new WSClient (wsdlLocation, serviceName)).

Can you give me any advice on how to further speed things up? How can i make creation of WS client objects faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't [busy wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_wait).

Either [sleep the current thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) for a short delay until checking again to see if the other threads have finished, or make use of [wait() / notify()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) to alert the current thread when the other actions are complete (this might be very messy inside a servlet though).

As for the process of importing new web-service clients into your application, if you need to process different WSDL's to generate client-side proxy code I am not sure of a better way. The only option may be to find a design where you don't need to keep generating new code at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a thread pool and assign calls to threads in that pool.  Check out [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

As far as faster creation of proxies, I suggest caching proxy objects in either cache or bind it to JNDI tree.  Handle exceptions properly for scenarios where cached reference goes stale so you can re-initialize them.

Comment: Creating WS endpoint object took almost 2s, so used singleton pattern (just 1 object) and that sped things very much. Tnx

Comment: caching does wonders for performance if handled well - isn't it?!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look at using the [Tomcat Comet extensions](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/aio.html) so you don't have to sit in a while loop.

If you MUST use the standard servlet structure, then put a LARGE sleep (something like `try{ Thread.sleep(1000); }catch(InterruptedException ie){}`) so you spend most of the time in the while loop sleeping. It is only marginally better than a simple while loop, so you REALLY want to look at the non-blocking options as linked above.

Comment: The production server is unfortunatelly JBOSS.

Comment: Well, it IS Tomcat 6, no? You should have access to the CometServlet implementation classes. It WILL need testing, but you SHOULD be able to get it to work.

Comment: OK sorry for being sloppy, will look at this thing tomorrow and report here. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Use ***Servlet 3.0's supported containers*** which has the support of ***asynchronous request***. Which will allow to suspend the request and resume after some long processing has happened. Asynchronous support is to make the server-side processing much more efficient. ***It overcomes connection and thread-consumpation issues.***

Few of these These support servlet 3.0:

- Tomcat
- Jetty
- Glassfish